# Should unchecked Exception be described in JavaDoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have the following code:

```
public User getUserById(Long id) {
checkUserExists(id);
return repo.findOne(id);
}

private void checkUserExists(Long id) {
    if (id == null || !repo.exists(id)) {
        throw new NoUserFoundException("No User exists with id: " +id);
    }
}
```

According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/RuntimeException.html):

> "Unchecked exceptions do not need to be declared in a method or constructor's throws clause if they can be thrown by the execution of the method or constructor and propagate outside the method or constructor boundary."

Do I have to describe the exception anyway in the JavaDoc (Without the `@throws` clause, but only describe?) What is the best way to describe such an unchecked exception in JavaDoc?

Comment: Would it be useful if people using your function were told that it might throw this exception? That's what javadocs are for. You can use `@throws` or `@exception` for unchecked exceptions as well as checked ones.

Comment: Oracle states that it doesn't *need* to be described there. It's not forbidden or discouraged. You can still do that and I think it's the appropriate way to do so.

Comment: Here is an example from the JDK : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: consider calling your method `ensureUserExists` rather than `checkUserExists`. I would expect `checkUserExists` to return a boolean.

Comment: @Michael I would expect `doesUserExist` to return a boolean. I would expect `checkUserExists` to raise an exception.

Comment: I agree with khelwood. But I think it's a better design to make methods that returns information instead of raising exception to inform the caller. So I think it'll be a better design to have a function `doesUserExists()` that return a boolean. Exception are made to inform of an anormal behaviour/data, in your case you make a function to chack if the user exists, which mean you expect that sometimes it doesn't exist, so it's not anormal to not have the user. So I'd return a boolean and not an exception. The caller can throw an exception if it expect the user to exist

Comment: @vinrichaud In this case, the method is used to check the preconditions for another method (`getUserById(Long id)`). It is certainly valid to throw an exception if a user with the given id does not exist. Another possibility is to return null. Which one is better depends on the typical usecase. Since Java 8 it is also possible to instead return an `Optional` and let the caller decide what to do when the user is not found: `getUserById(id).orElse(null)` or `getUserById(id).orElseThrow(...)`.

Comment: @f1sh Oracle states that where? Citation please.

Comment: @user207421 read the quote in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are writing Javadoc for the user of your method. If it's useful for that user to know that it may throw an exception, document it!

In your case, it seems that it is indeed useful for the user to know that a `NoUserFoundException` is thrown if the user is not found.

In other cases it's less useful. For example, in many cases the fact that a `NullPointerException` is thrown if a parameter is null is not documented in the Javadoc because it's often somehow implied that a parameter cannot be null.

By the way, Oracle is talking about the `throws` class appearing after the method declaration, not about the Javadoc. If you decide to document a non-checked exception, it makes sense to use the `@throws` clause.